# Huge list performance and memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, ado.net

I'm starting a new application. I run querys to the databases then I return a list of customs objects. Here is an example:

With this method i get all the records of a table. Example: SELECT ID,NAME, LASTNAME FROM PKR_PLAYER

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    List<TEntity> all = new List<TEntity>();
    String query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}",AllFieldsSelection,TableName);
    var data = SqlExecutionData.Create().WithConn(ConnectionString).WithQuery(query);
    foreach (IDataRecord record in SqlServerUtils.GetRecords(data))
    {
        all.Add(CreateOneFromRecord(record));
    }
    return all;
}
```

With this i create a TEntityObject with the data stored in record

```
private TEntity CreateOneFromRecord(IDataRecord record)
{
    var result = new TEntity();
    for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        ColumnMap colMap = maps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Column.Equals(record.GetName(i)));
        if (colMap == null || record.IsDBNull(i)) continue;
        object value = record.GetValue(i);
        colMap.PropertyInfo.SetValue(result, value, null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

How i execute the query

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetRecords(SqlExecutionData data)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(data.ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(data.Query, sqlConnection))
    {
        if (data.Parameters!=null && data.Parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (String key in data.Parameters.Keys)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, data.Parameters[key]);
        }
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (IDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
            }
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

In Brief, the idea is to iterate over a SqlDataReader (with yield return) and create an entity and finally stored it on a List.

I think this consumes a lot of resources. The query returns aprox 22k records and the method GetAll will be called very often. There will be times where GetAll Method will be called every 1 or 2 minutes.

I just execute a couple of times (10 times aprox) the method GetAll and the information on the Task Manager of windows shows me that the memory grows from 17MB to 45 MB in a few seconds.

I believe this code is not performance.

The question is: How can i make the code consumes less memory? May be i have to change the List, but what is the alternative?

Comment: Is this causing actual problems for your application? If not, don't waste time solving problems you are not having.

Comment: Does the data have lots of repeated strings by any chance? Some sneaky custom interning might help... Or: that could just be the necessary weight of your data.

Comment: Would it be possible to cache the data on the server instead of requesting it every minute? How often does it change?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you using deferred execution (yield) here?

Comment: @Oded Hi! Thanks! It may cause future problems. But the idea is to learn how can i code better in situations like this. ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell I have a few strings but they are all diferents. They are unique nick names of players.

Comment: @Magnus Cache could be a good solution. How often? Sometimes very often 100-200 times in a hour or two.

Comment: @YavgenyP Hi! Why deffered execution? It seems a good idea, i can use a SqlDataReader inside a generic method and i can create the custom object on a separete method based on the data. And i don't have to return a DataTable or DataSet and then create the custom object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `yield return` but then you need to change your method a bit.
this will minimize your memory consumption.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    String query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}",AllFieldsSelection,TableName);
    var data = SqlExecutionData.Create().WithConn(ConnectionString).WithQuery(query);
    foreach (IDataRecord record in SqlServerUtils.GetRecords(data))
    {
        yield return CreateOneFromRecord(record);
    }
}
```

this will consume much less memory, but it will also keep your connection to SQL Server open.
please read more on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Comment: Depending in the requirements returning an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `List<T>` might not work at all.

Comment: yes but you could do something like `new List<T>(GetAll())`.why should GetAll meet all your future requirements now.it hides the used implementation.maybe someone implement a superfast SqlDataReaderList, then you dont have to change anything beyond GetAll.

Comment: its a design question - you are right.i like to use interfaces to make the implementation abstract.

Comment: The problem I have with this is the potential misuse. if you assign the result of this function to a variable and than iterate the variable twice, this will actually call the database twice.

Comment: this is solved by documentation and understanding of IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I will read first about IEnumerable then i will comment. But i will like to close the sql sever connection.

Comment: it will be closed, after the enumerator has reached its end. such a call `foreach(var item in GetAll()) {}` or `var items = List(GetAll())` will work fine.

Comment: Doing `new List(GetAll())` will be exactly the same as you are doing now.

Comment: you're right it will eliminate the benefits of `yield`.
imho it is a documentational question.if `GetAll` is intended to be memory efficient then you must live with the fact, that a second iteration over its result will hit the database a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to delegate each item.
This is more explicit and you have more control over each item.
But you need to be careful, the delegate-call will block the iteration.
I prefer to use IEnumerable because it has so many features in .NET (PLinq, foreach, Collection-ctors).

```
public void IterateItems(Action<int, TEntity> handler)
{
    String query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}",AllFieldsSelection,TableName);
    var data = SqlExecutionData.Create().WithConn(ConnectionString).WithQuery(query);

    var index = 0;   
    foreach (IDataRecord record in SqlServerUtils.GetRecords(data))
    {
        handler(CreateOneFromRecord(index, record));
        index++;
    }
}
```

a memory efficient call:

```
public void MemoryEfficient()
{
    ProcessItems((index, item) => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", index, item));
}
```

collect items in a list:

```
public void FillAList()
{
    var list = new List<TEntity>();
    ProcessItems((index, item) => list.Add(item));
}
```